# insert line break instead of <p> in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

I have initialised TinyMCE as follows. I want to force line breaks when user presses enter and not  the paragraphs. I'm trying following, but not working. I'm using TinyMCE version 3_3_8.

```
tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "exact",
        theme: "advanced",
        elements: "textAreaId",
        cleanup: false,
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "",
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "",
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
        height: 200,
        width: 300,
    forced_root_block : false,
    force_br_newlines : true,
    force_p_newlines : false,
        oninit: InitPosition
    }); //init ends
```

I tried to define `forced_root_block : ""`, but still it is not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that not using `p` elements as root block can severely cripple the functionality of the editor. (from [TinyMCE docs](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#forced_root_block))

Answer (score 26):

Simply add `forced_root_block : false`

Or if you want a wrapper: `forced_root_block : 'div'`,

Works like a charm!

Comment: It doesn't work for 6.x+

Comment: It works for 4.2.0

Answer (score 15):

Instead try:

```
force_p_newlines : false,
force_br_newlines : true,
convert_newlines_to_brs : false,
remove_linebreaks : true,
```

Comment: Thanks, of great value!

Answer (score 10):

I faced the same situation with TinyMCE 4. All my "Enter" (keyboard) resulted in a new `<p>&nbsp</p>` injected.

I didn't want to use [`forced_root_block : false`](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#forced_root_block)  so I figured something out in the `tinymce.init` function (each empty paragraph will be cleaned directly):

```js
setup : function(editor) {

            editor.on('PostProcess', function(ed) {
                // we are cleaning empty paragraphs
                ed.content = ed.content.replace(/(<p>&nbsp;<\/p>)/gi,'<br />');
            });

        }
```

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#setup
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/class/tinymce.editor/#postprocess

Comment: This is great! By the way, in the current version I guess you should use onEditorChange event. There seems to be no generic PostProcess other than the paste plugin has.

Answer (score 10):

What worked for me was:

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    force_br_newlines : true,
    force_p_newlines : false,
    forced_root_block : ''
});
```

Each linebreak is producing br tag with these settings.

SOURCE: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:force_br_newlines

Answer (score 4):

The "forced_root_block : false" option works fine for TinyMCE 4.0.

Comment: Confirming this works on v5.8.x

Answer (score 2):

Insert in theme functions.php the following code:

```
    add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_switch_tinymce_p_br' ); 

    function my_switch_tinymce_p_br( $settings ) {
        $settings['forced_root_block'] = 'br';
        return $settings;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE On Mozilla Firefox adds `<div>` instead `<br>` or `<p>`.

I found the solution:

Open Mozilla Firefox and put in the address:
`about:config`

Search the option and turn false:
`editor.use_div_for_default_newlines`

Comment: This is not a good solution. Each user of the application would have to go to their advanced browse settings and update about:config – the application should handle it.

Answer (score 1):

in tinyMCE 5 I needed to add 1 extra parameter

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    valid_elements: 'br',
    force_br_newlines : true,
    force_p_newlines : false,
    forced_root_block : ''
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
force_br_newlines : true,
force_p_newlines : false,
forced_root_block : false,
```

anywhere in tinymce.init

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version, adding these parameters does not work:

```
force_br_newlines : true,
force_p_newlines : false,
forced_root_block : ''
```

this parameter must be added instead:

```
newline_behavior: 'linebreak'
```

as reported here:
[newline_behavior](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/content-behavior-options/#newline_behavior)